# When using Event listener the rpc call to program function does nothing and eventualy time limit will exceed and test fails

Tags: rpc, anchor-client, anchor-test

This block of code is giving the trouble..

```
let listener = null;
    
    //@ts-ignore
    let [event, slot] = await new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
      listener = program.addEventListener("Deposited", (event, slot) => {
        resolve([event, slot]);
      });
      program.rpc.redeem(
        new anchor.BN(redeemAmount),
        {
          accounts: {
            treasury,
            posMint,
            treasuryVault,
            userVault: userTreasuryVault,
            userPosVault,
            authority: user,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          },
          signers: [userKeypair]
        });  
    });
```

the call to the same function without the event listener will execute perfectly fine as I did here:

```
const tx = await program.rpc.redeem(
      new anchor.BN(redeemAmount),
      {
        accounts: {
          treasury,
          posMint,
          treasuryVault,
          userVault: userTreasuryVault,
          userPosVault,
          authority: user,
          tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        },
        signers: [userKeypair]
      });
```

I get no errors other than time limit exceeded..
How do I resolve this..?